# Azure APIM URL without API and Operation

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to serve a request by APIM policy only, is it required to have API  and operation for the same ?
for example
https://myapim/myapi/myoperation

I will serve this request from policy itself by calling few external APIs, do i need to create myapi API and myopration as blank operation ? or is there anyway to handle this ? currently i am getting 404 from APIM before reaching to policy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a dummy operation in my API by this my policy is getting executed and serving the request.

Answer (score 0):

When you create api in APIM, it will ask you to input your backend url like below screenshot.
[image]

And then when you create operation, if you input `/myoperation/` into the "**URL**" box like below:
[image]

It will request `https://your-backend-url/myoperation` in the backend, but your backend url is `https://your-backend-url`. So you may get 404 error. To solve this problem, you can just input `/` into the "**URL**" box when you create operation.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @hurry thanks but wanted to know if without having an operation APIM can serve the request or not by policy.  I guess APIM first check the url in route somewhere and then come to Policy

Comment: @Himanshu I'm not sure. You can have a try to click "All operation" and add the policy but not click a specific operation and then add the policy. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ur51.png).

Comment: Policy is on Product Level that is common for all the APIs within that product. Thanks this is done now